# Why do many examples use GlobalScope for android OnClickListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I wonder why many examples use GlobalScope for android OnClickListener.

example : https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#at-most-one-concurrent-job

I know to avoid using `GlobalScope` is recommended. Is there any reason for using `GlobalScope` in that case?

is it safe? or do I must use `Activity` or `Fragment` scope?

Comment: I think because that makes the example code work without having to set up the scoping in every snippet

Comment: It has something to do with using it for an actor and not for `launch` or `async`. You don't send off concurrent tasks with it, but set up a listener. Still, Kotlin doesn't have a complete story here and there's a reason why these APIs stayed experimental even as the general feature of coroutines went GA.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ok, I now know `actor` makes some difference. but, according to document, actor launches new coroutine too. And it wouldn't be cancelled if I use `GlobalScope` to use actor. what does make `actor` in `GlobalScope` be safe?

Comment: I think the whole lot of the event listener, the channel and the coroutine become unreachable when your GUI component becomes unreachable and subject to garbage collection. However, if the actor calls a suspendable function and your GUI gets destroyed while it's inside that function, the coroutine will survive.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for comment! In many cases, listeners have to call suspendable function like network job causing coroutine to be survive. is it ok if I guarantee that suspendable function will be terminated in short time? even if I use `GlobalScope`

Comment: That depends on what the code does. In my project i got crashes from the coroutine trying to update a GUI component that had its `context` nulled out and other variations of that. So it didn't matter how short the delay was, as soon as I acted upon a destroyed activity's GUI tree, i got into trouble.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik it's another problem... It seems that coroutines must be cancelled when GUI tree destroyed. Regardless what its scope is. right?

Comment: The point of the scope is to do this for you. If you create the coroutine in the scope whose lifecycle is bound to the GUI's lifecycle, it will be cancelled. But you are still responsible for writing the explicit code that cancels the scope's job (the basic example provided in the documentation of `CoroutineScope`).